# Spring Application Context in JavaFX Application

Tags: spring, javafx, dependency-injection, autowired, applicationcontext

I interested in using a `ApplicationContext` in a JavaFX application. I ask myself if there is a smarter way to handle the `ApplicationContext` as an attribute of `Application` subclass itself.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("...")
public class Gui extends Application {

   private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
   }

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
    */

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {       
      context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Gui.class);
      //...         
    }       
}
```

I purpose to separate the `ApplicationContext` from `Gui.class` and furthermore to use the `@Autowired` annotation for the injection of spring components in the `Gui.class`.

Answer (score 3):

First, separate the application configuration from the `Application` subclass. JavaFX will create an instance of the Application subclass for you, and there should be only one instance of that class. Spring will create an instance of any configuration classes, so, even though you don't have access to them, you end up with multiple instances of the Application class, which is not the intended use.

As for the separation you are looking for, what I think you are wanting is to separate the creation and interaction with the `ApplicationContext` from the work of building and configuring the UI, and making it interact with the business tier for the application, etc. However, I think you are looking at this backwards from the way you should. The `Application` class, and specifically its `start()` method, is the entry point for a JavaFX application. The FX framework does some housekeeping at startup (starting the FX toolkit, etc), creates an instance of that class, and invokes the start method. Since this is where you do the basic assembly of the application, it's the natural and correct place to create the `ApplicationContext` and get one or two beans from it. If you want to separate this from creating and configuring the UI, it's the creation and configuration of the UI that should be moved elsewhere. The sole responsibility of the `Application` class should be to start up the application: this way there is no state to inject into that class at all.

Using this approach, a minimal Spring-powered FX application might look like:

AppConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Service service() {
        return new Service();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Gui gui() {
        return new Gui();
    }
}
```

Service.java:

```
public class Service {

    public String confirmationMessage() {
        return "You have been confirmed";
    }
}
```

Gui.java (note this is not the `Application` subclass now, but it does almost all the GUI work):

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Gui {

    @Inject
    private Service service ;

    private VBox view ;
    private Label label ;

    public Gui() {
        Button button = new Button("Press for confirmation");
        label = new Label();
        label.setVisible(false);
        button.setOnAction(e -> label.setVisible(true));

        view = new VBox(5, label, button);
        view.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        view.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        label.setText(service.confirmationMessage());
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }
}
```

Finally, the `Application` class, Main.java. Note this doesn't really do any GUI work: it just manages the application lifecycle: creates the `ApplicationContext`, gets a bean from it representing the main view, and shows it in the primary stage. All the actual GUI work is delegated to the `MainView` class, whose instances are managed by Spring.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private AbstractApplicationContext context ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Parent mainView = context.getBean(Gui.class).getView();
        primaryStage.setScene( new Scene(mainView) );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        context.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You can extend this approach so that it uses a full MVC/MVP design for the presentation tier, use FXML if you want, etc.

Comment: Thanks!!! I think this is a nice way to seperate responsibilities of the classes.